Time based trigger activated multiple times
I created a trigger which runs a function every weekday around 8pm, but I accidentally have run this trigger multiple times, so the function gets activated 3 times instead of once. How do I fix this problem?
Here's my code for the function and the trigger underneath:
function take1() {
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(startDate, "GMT-6", "MM/dd/YY");
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'), true);
spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(dateString);
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('2:40').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(),         spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
spreadsheet.getRange('C12').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(), 40);
};

function createTriggers() {
var days = \[ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,  
ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY\];
for (var i=0; i\<days.length; i++) {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("take1")
.timeBased().onWeekDay(days\[i\])
.atHour(20).create();
}
}

I found some code that is supposed to delete  triggers but I'm not sure how to make it fit my code specifically:
function deleteTimers() {
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  }
} 


function take1(e) {
  if (e.day-of-week < 6) {
    //put your function here
  };
}

function createTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "take1").forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("take1").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(20).create();
}

